# Search object with a date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a dashboard with a date range, the user can search activy for the period he wants.

I have different models that I manage with the same Dasboard

For example I want to find:

- the users registration in a date range
- the sales in a date range
- etc...

I have buttons that represent the models, on click they render the appropriated partial.

I can search for date range but it only works for the first partial **sales** in this case, if I click on the next button which is **users** the search redirect on the first partial **sales**

This is because the dashboard action show renders by default **sales** I would need something that renders the current active button...

Could you help please me to find how to do this?

below some code:

**dashboard.rb**

```
class Dashboard

 attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

 def initialize(params)
    params ||= {}
    @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from],Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s)
    @date_to   = parsed_date(params[:date_to], (Date.today + 1).to_s)
 end

 def article_date_range
    Article.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
 end

 private 

 def parsed_date(date_string, default)
    Date.parse(date_string)
    rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
    default
 end
end
```

the show action in **dashboards_controller.rb**

```
  def show
    @button ||= set_button || :sales
    @dashboard = Dashboard.new(params[:search])
    @articles = @dashboard.article_date_range
    @articles = @articles.order('created_at ASC') 
 end

  private 

  def set_button
   button = dashboard__params[:button]&.to_sym and [:sales, :users].include?(button) and button
 end
```

this form and buttons are in the dashboard **show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag admin_dashboard_path, method: :get do  %>
    <%= text_field_tag "search[date_from]", @dashboard.date_from, class: "datepicker" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "search[date_to]", @dashboard.date_to, class: "datepicker" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Rechercher", class: "btn btn-main" %>
<% end %>

 #the buttons that "redirect" to the appropriated partial

<% [:sales, :users, :articles].each do |button| %>
   <li class="tabs list-inline-item <%= params[:button] == button.to_s ? "tabs__item--active" : "tabs__item--inactive" %>">
    <%= link_to admin_dashboard_url(button: button) do  %>
      <%= button.capitalize %>
    <% end %>
   </li>
<% end %>
```

> ### Update
>
> The idea is that the user select a date range and then click on the buttons to see the activity in the selected date range for either articles sales and users (without selecting again the date range) 
>   [image]

Comment: Side note, ranges can be searched using a [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html). `where(created_at: @date_from..@date_to)`

Comment: yes I use that somewhere else ;)

Comment: Have you tried something like: `@button ||= (set_button || :sales)`?

Comment: yes but that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because, `dashboard__params[:button]` is always `nil`. Because in your search form there is no `input` field with `name` set to `button`. If you are thinking about `<%= link_to admin_dashboard_url(button: button) do  %>`, it's outside the html form.

So method `set_button` is returning `nil`.

So the first line of your `show` action always returns `:sales` as this is the default value if `set_button` returns nil.

I would suggest to add an `hidden input` field in your search form. Then use javascript to prevent the default form submit behavior, set the value of that `hidden input` field with appropriate value (`sales` or `user`), then submit the form using javascript.

## **Update 1**

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag admin_dashboard_path, method: :get do  %>
    <%= text_field_tag "search[date_from]", @dashboard.date_from, class: "datepicker" %>
    <%= text_field_tag "search[date_to]", @dashboard.date_to, class: "datepicker" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'button', 'sales', id: 'button' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Rechercher", class: "btn btn-main" %>
<% end %>

 #the buttons that "redirect" to the appropriated partial

<% [:sales, :users, :articles].each do |button| %>
   <li class="tabs list-inline-item <%= params[:button] == button.to_s ? "tabs__item--active" : "tabs__item--inactive" %>">
    <%= link_to admin_dashboard_url(button: button) id: "#{button}_click" do  %>
      <%= button.capitalize %>
    <% end %>
   </li>
<% end %>
```

Now using javascript before submitting the search form, set the value of the hidden_filed.

## **Update 2**

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to '#', id: "#{button}_click", class: 'model_link'  do  %>
  <%= button.capitalize %>
<% end %>
```

**javascript (assuming you have jQuery)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.model_link').click(function() {
        var buttonName = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
        $('#button').val(buttonName);
        $('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @mehedi, I'll try this

Comment: with this suggestion I need to create a  form for each model? I actually want just only one form..

Comment: @johan I have updated my answer showing how to modify the your `show` view. Just one thing, are you redirecting to a partial or rendering a partial? Because technically I don't think you can redirect to a partial, you can only redirect to a view.

Comment: I am not comfortable with javascript,  I am supposed to write an event listener ?

Comment: @johan Are the users submitting the search form first and then clicking the `link_to admin_dashboard_url(button: button)`. Because I see there are already a submit button in the search form `<%= submit_tag "Rechercher", class: "btn btn-main" %>`

Comment: The user can search for a date range. The first partial is rendered by default, and if the user click on the `link_to admin_dashboard_url(button: button)`he can see with the same date range `:users` and `:articles`

Comment: @johan Glad, it helped! :)

Comment: there was just a small typo `click(fucntion() `otherwise it's SO coool !  ;-)